# Период дроби c++

Tags: c++, математика

Насколько большой может быть длина периода дроби типа int/int ?

Comment: что за _длина периода дроби типа int/int_?

Comment: 1/3 ---- длина периода = 1, т.к. 1/3 = 0,(3)

Comment: в числителе и знаменателе int

Comment: @Grundy, есть два числа - числитель и знаминатель, оба помещаются в int32. Если выполнить деление, то получится некая десятичная периодическая дробь. Вопрос, какова наибольшая длина периода (и, вероятно, предпериода) при этом возможна (в десятичных цифрах).

Comment: @Генадий, а как насчёт 1/6? Тут период состоит из одной цифры и предпериод из 1 цифры. Для твоего вопроса подразумевается, что это следует рассматривать как 2 или как 1?

Comment: а как это связывается с `c++`?

Comment: имеется в виду правильное деление, а не округлённое double/float

Comment: длина периода => длина периода, а не "предпериода"

Comment: @Grundy, как минимум, типичной битностью int'а. Или нужна программа на Си++, которая находи ответ. Я пока не придумал способа лучше перебора, но он точно существует. Я раньше думал про такие вещи.

Comment: мне не нужны программы, только ответ на вопрос; связано с c++ диапозоном int

Comment: например, при 1/97 там более 90 знаков в периоде, а нужна максимальная длина

Comment: @Генадий, тогда, насколько я понимаю, в ответе знаменатель не кратен ни 2, ни 5, поскольку они не увеличивают длину периода. Верно?

Comment: C++ тут не при чём. Длина периода — вопрос чисто математический. В C++ действительные числа имеют ограниченную точность, так что о периоде говорить не приходится.

Comment: в ответе должно быть число = длине периода) с остальным я сам разберусь

Comment: @VladD, а где ты в вопросе видишть действительные числа? Там спрашивается о рациональных. Скорее всего ему это вообще для определения размера буфера под число надо.

Comment: омг, если бы числа были не int/int, то период может быть бесконечный вообще (если считать периодом дробную часть иррационального числа), а если int/int - то длина периода - конечное число

Comment: ну так и пробегитесь перебором по всем

Comment: @Генадий, вопрос понятен.

Comment: @Grundy, (2^31)^2 - ну да, конечно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну на самом деле меньше. если по ходу пропускать всякие четные и кратные

Comment: короче тут надо либо математическое доказательство, либо ещё как-то проверить

Comment: можно проверить 1/(положительные int), а потом домножить на максимальный int по идее

Comment: @Qwertiy: А у рациональных чисел нет понятия периода. Числитель и знаменатель, и всё.

Comment: Что то я совсем запутался, о чем вы вообще. int целочисленный тип. Деление двух int C++ будет выполнять как DIV процессора, которая дает целочисленный результат и остаток в другом регистре. Если числа не преобразовать предварительно в float деления с плавающей точкой не будет. А если преобразовывать - то вопрос к точности хранения float и double. А если вопрос чисто теоретический, то 1/3 уже даст бесконечный период, и вопрос длины его хранения исключительно к типу данных в который мы решим его положить

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31946/discussion-on-question-by----c).

Comment: http://kvant.mccme.ru/pdf/2000/02/kv0200semenova.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Длина периода гарантированно меньше значения знаменателя, поскольку для зацикливания требуется получить повтор остатка от деления.

Предположу, что максимальная длина достигается на максимальном простом знаменателе `d`, не являющемся делителем `10^k-1` для любого `k`. Причём, эта длина составит `p-1`. в качестве числителя взять `1`.

Доказать не могу и не проверял.
Если никто не проверит, поэксперементирую вечером.

Comment: т.е. максимальная длина около 2 147 483 647 * 10^10 ?

Comment: т.е. 10 * 10:10 ,

Comment: ок все понял бб

Comment: @Генадий, а откуда умножение? Просто около 2^31.

Answer (score 3):

2<sup>31</sup>-2 = 2147483646.
Наибольшее простое число формата int равно 2<sup>31</sup>-1 = 2147483647, это простое число <s>Ферма</s> Мерсенна.
А уникальных остатков на один меньше. Положительный числитель - любой, кроме знаменателя.

Comment: Как доказать, что все уникальные остатки встретятся? Например, у 11 период только 2, а не 10.

Comment: вот кому интересно https://oeis.org/A001913

Answer (score 2):

Нулевой, поскольку деление `int/int` - целочисленное, так что в результате получается целое число. Это вам не Питон :)